# Host not resolving, ping is

Tags: macos, dns, routing

I have two network cards on my Mac OS X. 
One for my corporate, the other one is my wlan. 
For all internal stuff, the corporate one should be used.

I configured following:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 --interface en4
```

Then I added a file `/etc/resolver/company.ads` with following content:

```
nameserver 10.110.29.100
```

My Wifi card is set to default.

ping works, Microsoft Remote Desktop works, `host` works into the corporate. Internet over Wifi works.
But opening internal websites do not work. `wget` or `curl` do not work.

What am I missing?

**Update:**
My routing table

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           44        0     en0
default            10.170.78.1        UGScI           0        0     en4
10                 link#7             UCSc            7        0     en4
10.170.78/24       link#7             UCS             0        0     en4
10.170.78.11       127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3  2459834     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
169.254.255.255    link#4             UHLSW           0        0     en0
192.168.1          link#4             UCS             5        0     en0
192.168.1.1        8:60:6e:cb:da:38   UHLWIir        47      613     en0   1148
192.168.1.2        28:cf:e9:18:8b:2d  UHLWIi          2     1823     en0    214
192.168.1.3        127.0.0.1          UHS             0       50     lo0
192.168.1.33       f4:f9:51:49:6:1a   UHLWI           0        0     en0    587
192.168.1.188      68:a8:6d:5:f2:76   UHLWI           0      585     en0   1193
192.168.1.247      88:53:95:54:84:35  UHLWI           0        0     en0    822
192.168.56         link#10            UC              1        0 vboxnet

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::10ce:527:3d6:490f%en0             2c:b4:3a:6:25:27                UHLWI           en0
fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe18:8b2d%en0           28:cf:e9:18:8b:2d               UHLWI           en0
fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe18:8d31%en0           28:cf:e9:18:8d:31               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en4/64                           link#7                          UCI             en4
fe80::7211:24ff:fe8c:de53%en4           70:11:24:8c:de:53               UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%en4/32                           link#7                          UmCI            en4
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%en4/32                           link#7                          UmCI            en4
```

Comment: most likely it is asking the wrong dns server for host names.

Comment: ping and some other tools do work. How can I get the browser to use for some domains the other nameserver. Shouldn't it use the default name resolution of the OS?

Comment: yes, it should use the host DNS, but you only get one; DNS servers are set NIC by NIC, not route by route (at least in any normal OS; who knows about macs...) so you need a DNS server that knows both zones, or is configured to forward requests that result in NX responses to the other DNS server for resolution, and proxy it back to the client. DNS forwarding is pretty easy if you have control of the DNS server. Note that defining multiple DNS servers for a NIC will not cause it to check multiple servers for each request.

Comment: Ok, I found out that chrome gets the ip resolved but it seems that it uses the wrong NIC to reach this site, whereas ping and others are using the right one.

Comment: whats your route table look like?

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Ping and RDP protocols are not like HTTP. HTTP (used by 'wget' and 'curl') also has the server's IP address/host name in the HTTP header, typically in 'Host:'. Also, DNS A or AAAA records are not the same as DNS WWW records.

Use your browser's dev tools/plugin such as LiveHeader to check which IP/host name your internal web sites are using. This is the name that must be DNS-resolvable by either your local hosts file, or a private DNS server on your 10.* subnet with a WWW record.

When the DNS server/hosts file replies, your computer's routing table must route the IP that it returns (use 'nslookup' to check) through en4.

This is not Mac-specific. It's built into the DNS and HTTP protocols.